# Android, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP seems doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

In my menu I have some items. Home is an item of it that I want to be root of my application and whenever user clicks on it, Android clear stack and then come back to main screen.

This is my code:

```
menu.setOnItemClickedListener(new MenuClickedListener() {
            public void eventOccured(int id) {          

                Intent intent = null;
                switch(id) {
                    case 1: intent = new Intent(context, More.class);           break;
                    case 2: intent = new Intent(context, FavoriteScreen.class); break;
                    case 3: intent = new Intent(context, VideoShowList.class);  break;
                    case 4: intent = new Intent(context, ShoppingList.class);   break;
                    case 5: intent = new Intent(context, MainScreen.class); 
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            break;                  
                }       

                if(intent != null)
                    context.startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });
```

Menu works fine but it seems flag doesn't work because from Home screen, i go to second and third screen then i click on Home item of menu and come back to home screen. Now, when i click on back button, i go to third screen, second screen and Home screen.

I have designed this menu as widget in order to setup it one time and reuse it on all of my screens.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` inplace of   `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            yourActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I thought the same, the reason 'm confused is that if no flag added yet then we use addFlag() else setFlag() what a fish!!!

Comment: This does not helps

Answer (score 20):

I have tried **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** But haven't got proper solution  so finally this helps me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```

This clears all the stack and run only **LoginActivity**

Comment: perfect answer +1

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to start an Activity to be the only one existing (that is, **clear the whole backstack**), use the following flags:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
```

Requires API-Level >= 11.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, my problem was that activity in intent has launchMode="singleInstance". changed to singleTask and code worked as it should.

Answer (score -3):

maybe this works :

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```