# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP doesn't deletes the activity stack

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing the application in which i want to close whole application on button click. I know in android we should not think about to close the application because android does that automatically from this [Is quitting an application frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon?lq=1). but yet i want to close my application.

So what i am doing to close application is i am using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag to delete the activity stack.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, FinishActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

And in onCreate of `FinishActivity.class` i am calling `this.finish()` but application is not get closed and previous activity gets reopened.

FinishActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.finish();
}
```

**Update :**

Here is the scenario

```
MainActivity->Activity2->Activity3->FinishActivity
```

Here `Activity2` is gets opened after finishing the activity.

How do i achieve this? Any idea and suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: are you doing anything in FinishActivity or just calling this.finish()?

Comment: just calling `this.finish()`

Comment: why do you want to keep an activity just to call finish()? just call finish() in Activity3 or any other Activity of yours instead of sending an intent to finishActivity.class. if you really need it, then use the splash screen concept. use a handler thread for 2 or 3 sec and then call finish.

Comment: Thanks, my main goal is to close whole application on button click

Comment: try system.exit(1) instead of finish().

Comment: No success with `system.exit(1)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22361/discussion-between-santhosh-and-juned)

Comment: I tried the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881010/955321, and it works for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this--

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, FinishActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

**Edited--New Answer and would work perfectly..**

just taking an example...do it accordingly what your project needs--

I am taking three `Activity` class A, B and C..and I have applied a close button on the view of class C Activity. If you want then by the Back button you can go to the previous Activity and when you press the close button then you would exit from apps..have a look--

```
public class AActivity extends Activity {

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
        final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (resultCode == 5) {
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

Take next class activity--

```
   public class B extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.b);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, C.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 2);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
        final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (resultCode == 5) {
        setResult(5);
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

Take last activity--

```
    public class C extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.c);
}

    // close button..set by xml view..you can set it by button listener.
public void close(View v) {
    setResult(5);
    finish();
}
}
```

Hopefully, it would solve your problem..cheers!

Comment: Do finish(); before calling next activity...so no need to use anything.

Comment: yeah but by using this i won't be able go previous activity using back button

Comment: Try this instread of finish();--
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Comment: this function working fine it quits the FinishActivity but then previous screens is opened mean that Flags are not clearing the stack of activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22383/discussion-between-juned-and-hulk)

Comment: hey juned i resolved your problem---
use startActivityForResult(); instread of using startActivity();...ok
use this on every activity when you start and set the result..

Answer (score 35):

Give this a try. This should clear your activity stack.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 27):

This finally worked for me 100% of the time. I tried all of the flags standalone, never worked for all instances of the code. Used all the flags everywhere I want this functionality, about 5 different places, and it now works.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(actvSignIn.this, actvNearbyPlaces.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Comment: I tried so many solutions given in other answers. But this is what worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From documentation for `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.

So to get it work your `FinishActivity` must be first one in your Activity stack. In any other cases this solution wouldn't give you anything.

You must perform several steps to perform this:

1) Make `FinishActivity` as your launcher activity.

2) Do not provide any view for it and start first `Activity` of your application directly from `onCreate` callback :

3) Redefine `onRestart` callback:

Code sample:

```
private boolean isNeedToContinue = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isNeedToContinue) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(this,FirstVisibleActivity.class));
                    isNeedToContinue = false;
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    finish();
    isNeedToContinue = false;
}
```

I guess this is all you need. Good luck!

Comment: so what will be the better way to implement this ?

Answer (score 3):

setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

apart from that set launchMode to "singleTop" in FinishActivity definition in xml,
overwrite onNewIntent method , you can pass some additional information as part of intent , instated of finishing your activity in onCreate finish it in onNewIntent method of activity  based on some signal from calling activity or simply finish it based on your need  .
It maybe possible your other activities have different lauchmodes that's why they are not finishing .

Comment: i haven't set any launch modes to other activities and i have already tried with setting a launchmode to `SingleTop` to `finishActivity.class` in manifest.

Comment: you can try this : set launchMode to "singleTop" in FinishActivity definition in xml, overwrite onNewIntent method and finish your activity there .

Comment: How to overwrite that in onNewIntent, can you please make it clear ?

Comment: Should be used in your activity class  @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
 
 super.onNewIntent(intent); 
}

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have the following should work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, FinishActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

For API level < 11, `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is not available. Instead I used `IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` from support library.

See [IntentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/IntentCompat.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)

Might help someone stumbling across.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this Way this is work for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, FinishActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

instead of your code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, FinishActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: @Hulk there is differece: intent.addFlags and intent.setFlags

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, FinishActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: are you doing anything in FinishActivity or just calling this.finish()?

Comment: could you check whether you are using intent.setFlags or intent.addFlags.

Comment: after calling finish in FinishActivity, are u seeing Activity3 or someother activity. ?

Comment: Activity2 see my update, i have created simple app to test this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22385/discussion-between-juned-and-santhosh)

Comment: everytime you start another activity using intent use

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 

I mean when u start Activity3 from Activity2 use the same line. also from MainActivity to Activity2.

Comment: Still no change having same problem

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, FinishActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: It worked for me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MoreOptionsActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use `finishAffinity()` function in last activity like:

```
finishAffinity()
startHomeActivity()
```

Hope it'll be useful.