# How to clear the activity stack and bring a running activity to foreground in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am starting *activities(one or more)* of another android application from one of the *activities(Activity A)* of my application to run some test scripts. After running, I want Activity A to be brought to the foreground the activities of the other application to be closed.

I am trying to achieve this by setting the `launchMode` of **Activity A** as `singleTop` in the `manifest` and using this snippet:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //Clear Top Flag
startActivity(intent);
```

I have also tried using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when launching **ActivityA** which will clear the entire task and create a new instance of **ActivityA** whereas I want the running instance of **ActivityA** to be brought to foreground

I have also tried to implement code samples from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209124/intent-flag-activity-clear-top-doesnt-deletes-the-activity-stack)

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074980/bring-application-to-front-after-user-clicks-on-home-button

Comment: @m0skit0 - This won't work for me as **Activity A** is not the root activity for my app.

Comment: I don't think it matters if it's the root activity or not. The activity is specified in the `Intent`.

Comment: @m0skit0 - The flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

This will bring the specified activity to top of the stack and clear rest of them.