# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP not working

Tags: android, back-stack

My Application Flow:

Login->Profile->UpdateProfile->ChangePass

**All of my activitys extends FragmentActivity**

When I press button in ChangePass Activity I call this code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

So It should start LoginActivity and when I press back from LoginActivity then Application should close...But When I press back button from Login Activity the flow is:

ChangePass->UpdateProfile->Profile->Login

**Why My back stack is not cleared ?**

Note:

I have applied all these solutions but not working:
[1.link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881010)
[2.link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14209228)

Comment: Add the flag: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: This should work . can you post your manifest

Comment: What Android do you use? If Android 5.0+ (Lollipop) then maybe check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944455/flag-activity-clear-top-not-working-on-5-0-devices

Answer (score 4):

Very late reply though.
But might help others as it worked for me.

Developers sometimes confuse `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

**Use this instead**
`intentRestart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following way -

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

For more alternatives and details check [intent-flag-activity-clear-top-doesn't-deletes-the-activity-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209124/intent-flag-activity-clear-top-doesnt-deletes-the-activity-stack). The post explains with the result code perfectly and with the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the old flags try appending one.
Setflag replace theold flags.

Try using addFlags.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the task and create new.

```
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

This might create a temporary white screen while transition. To remove this defect.
Add this to your App theme.

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Enjoy Android!